# C# MVC 5 Code First Approach Multiple Connection String in single DBContext class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I am working on C# WEB API build with MVC 5 Code First Approach where I encountered with situation in which I need to use two separate SQL connection strings to process data respectively. But I am unaware of how to include another connection in my dbcontext class and call the same in controller.

Below is code snippet from DB Context Class for reference:

[image]

Below is code snippet of controller calling existing connection string:

[image]

In code snippet 1 provided above, I want to pass another connection string and use the same in my controller function as shown in code snippet 2 above.

Comment: Why two connections strings?  When you create the mapping with Entity the connection string is automatically created.  May be you should look at the configuration file and the csproj file to better understand the mapping.

Comment: @jdweng, Thanks for your reply first, you are correct in manner as connection string is automatically created but I need to access some data from another SQL server instance, in that case I need to mention different SQL server in my web.config file. Here where I am unaware of process, Please help!

Comment: Different instance of the Server on same machine or different database on same instance? Is database same structure? Same server you can put int command text "Use Name; Select * from ABC" where Name is the database name.If you have more than one instance You need to change the connection string to correct instance.In posted code you have a string "default" which can be replace with a variable.See examples at : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string and https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/